# Java doing a For loop but also using an iterator for Linked List ( "For, While") Loop?

Tags: java, loops, iterator, for-loop, linked-list

I apologize for the basic question but my newness to Java is causing me some frustration and I am unable to find an elegant way to do this from my searches.

I want to iterate through a linked list using a For construct but also have an numerical iterator so that I can break the loop after a certain number of iterations.

I have this LL that I am iterating through:

```
LinkedList<SearchResult> docSearch;
```

I tried doing it like this but then only the iterator part worked (the result was always stuck on the first entry for each iteration)

```
for (SearchResult result : docSearch) while (iter2 < 50)  { 

//do stuff
iter2 = iter2 + 1;
}
```

Any advice is appreciated

Comment: what exactly do you want? looping through all elements, but break after a certain number of iterations? What if there are less than that "certain number" of elements in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to do that sort of checking, then I would just do it with an if in the block.

```
for (SearchResult result : docSearch)  {
  if (iter2 >= 50) break;

  //do stuff
  iter2 += 1;
}
```

Comment: ah ok thanks (think you meant to leave out the while part ?), I had used a similar method of doing this before in Python but was unaware I could do this in Java.. thanks

Comment: I guess you will edit that `while (iter2 < 50)` in the first line away :)

Comment: Yes, that was a copy-and-paste fail. I did mean to leave out the while part.

Answer (score 1):

It will be better to use regular for..loop syntax to handle your need

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50 && i < docSearch.getSize(); i++ ) {
    SearchResult result = docSearch.get(i);
}
```

Just because Java support for-each loop, does not mean we have to use it every time. I find using regular for..loop syntax is easier to read where your condition is isolated in 1 place. If you use for-each with break then you have 2 places which affect your code flow.

Comment: For a linked list you should not use indexed access, though - your loop has O(n^2) run time (with n = 50), an iterator-based variant has only O(n).  (It might not matter for n = 50, but it will matter for larger sizes.)

Answer (score 0):

where did you assign the value of iter2?

try

```
for (SearchResult result : docSearch) 
{
  int iter2 = 0;
  while (iter2 < 50)  { 

  //do stuff
  iter2 = iter2 + 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do this:

```
for (SearchResult result : docSearch) while (iter2 < 50)  { 

//do stuff
iter2 = iter2 + 1;
}
```

It's the exact same as doing this:

```
for (SearchResult result : docSearch) {

    while (iter2 < 50)  { 

    //do stuff
    iter2 = iter2 + 1;
    }
}
```

You can get around this in a number of ways. One is a break (although some frown upon this as spaghetti code.

```
for (SearchResult result : docSearch) { 
if(iter2 >= 50) break;
//do stuff
iter2 = iter2 + 1;
}
```

You can use a standard for loop and put the two conditions into the condition section

```
Iterator<SearchResult> iter = docSearch.iterator();
for(SearchResult result = iter.next(); iter.hasNext() && iter2 < 50; result = iter.next()) {
   // do stuff
   iter2 = iter2 + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (SearchResult result : docSearch)  {
  if (iter2++ >= 50) break;
  //do stuff
}
```

Here might be a nice place for a post-incrementation too. :)